# Search for Text and Copy Files to Location Based on that text powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a directory that our work order program dumps xml files into.  I need to search those files for a specific string and then copy them to another location based on that string.  I modified the below code from another post and while I don't get any errors it also doesn't work.  I'm very much a scripting newbie so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
[string] $FileDirectory = "D:\Temp";
[string] $OutputPath  = "D:\Temp\Temp_NY";
[string] $OutputPath2 = "D:\Temp\TEMP_FL";


foreach ($FilePath in Get-ChildItem $FileDirectory | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName)
{
[string] $Header = Get-Content $FilePath -First 0

if ($Header -match 'PARTNER |TEST_NY') {
    Copy-Item $FilePath $OutputPath
}
elseif ($Header -match 'PARTNER |TEST_FL*') {
    Copy-Item $FilePath $OutputPath2
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The header would be `-First 1` (first line only). `-First 0` returns nothing. Try:

```
$FileDirectory = "D:\Temp";
$OutputPath  = "D:\Temp\Temp_NY";
$OutputPath2 = "D:\Temp\TEMP_FL";   

Get-ChildItem $FileDirectory | ? { !$_.PSIsContainer } | ForEach-Object {

    $FilePath = $_.FullName
    $Header = Get-Content $FilePath -First 1

    if ($Header -match 'PARTNER |TEST_NY') {
        Copy-Item $FilePath $OutputPath
    }
    elseif ($Header -match 'PARTNER |TEST_FL*') {
        Copy-Item $FilePath $OutputPath2
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm getting an access error now. Get-Content : Access to the path 'D:\Temp\TEMP_FL' is denied.
At line:8 char:15
+     $Header = Get-Content $FilePath -First 1
+               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (D:\Temp\TEMP_FL:String) [Get-Content], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetContentReaderUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
 
Get-Content : Access to the path 'D:\Temp\TEMP_NY' is denied.
At line:8 char:15
+     $Header = Get-Content $FilePath -First 1

Comment: Just checked my output directories and it moved all of the files into the Temp_NY directory even though it threw the access denied message.  So it's not copying the files based on the search string.  Figured out the access denied issue.  Since those subdirectories Temp_FL and Temp_NY in are the same directory as the files it tried to run the script against them as well.  Added -af to the Get-ChildItem command and that resolved it.  Now I just need to figure out why it's copying all of the files into one directory.

Comment: I thought the -af was a better solution because it's a simple switch and does the job.  I'll look up the PSIsContainer to see what it is.  I'm sure it will be useful in the future.  Working my way through some Powershell training but this was an urgent need.  I've checked your answer. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem. Yes, I believe it filters at filesystem-provider level which is faster, if not it's at least easier to use, but it's a PS 3.0+ switch. I like to keep my answers PS 2.0 compatible when I can. :-)